# Excluir palavras Repetidas de Variavel

Tags: php

Segue o código:

```
$selbanco = "SELECT * FROM exemplo WHERE id=5";
$querybanco = mysql_query($selbanco);


while($teste=mysql_fetch_array($querybanco)){

  $testando = $teste['teste'];
}

<td id="idcampo"> ><?php 
  if($teste1>$teste2){
      echo "$testando";
      } 
          else {
echo "(Agurde)" </td>


<script>var exemplo = $("#idcampo").html();</script>
$exemplo = "<script>document.write(exemplo)</script>";

echo $exemplo;
```

Ao exibir essa variável exemplo com `echo` ele retorna "exemplo exemplo" , teria algum comando ou alguma coisa que possa usar para retornar apenas "exemplo" sem repetir a palavra?

Obs: A variável que pego no banco de dados vem duplicada ("exemplo exemplo")

Comment: me mostre onde esta a resposta pra minha pergunta ?

Comment: Exatamente na sua pergunta anterior. o fato de você não entender não faz com que não seja duplicata. Basta usar o código da resposta que você mesmo aceitou, e aplicar antes do `echo`. Sugeriria você elaborar melhor suas perguntas, aqui todo mundo quer ajudar, mas se você não explicar direito, fica dificil. Espero que entenda que para obter uma resposta que resolva seu problema, é fundamental que você consiga explicá-lo adequadamente.

Comment: A resposta nao funciona para esta pergunta, pois capturo a variável de um modo diferente, o codigo passado na pergunta anterior NÃO SERVE COMO RESPOSTA PARA ESTA PERGUNTA.

Comment: Ela serve, mas você está se perdendo ao misturar PHP com JS.

Comment: por isso estou pedindo ajuda , se não precisasse de ajuda não estava aqui

Comment: implementei o código e ele continua duplicando a variável, ELE NÃO SERVE.

Comment: Então, aí você tem que ajudar a gente e colocar o problema exatamente como é na realidade. Se ficar jogando perguntas pela metade, fica a comunidade inteira perdendo tempo com coisa que não te serve. E como eu disse, se você não sabe minimamente o que está fazendo, a culpa não é da comunidade. De qualquer forma, se alguém entender que não é duplicata, é só votar pra reabrir. Fica a sugestão de você criar um [mcve], e aí podemos ajudar em cima dele.

Comment: Por isso criei esta pergunta, para explicar o problema corretamente, pois já tinha aceitado a resposta na outra e apos aceitar n iria mudar a pergunta.

Comment: E você aceitou sem ela servir? Perceba que você está aproveitando mal os recursos da comunidade. Como eu disse, se você tentar usar com mais atenção, vai ser melhor pra você e pra gente. Isso que eu estou tentando te dizer é pra ajudar você também. Só com o que você pôs aqui na pergunta, o problema continua o mesmo. Se aquela não serve, clique no [edit] nessa aqui, e explique seu problema com um exemplo funcional do problema.

Comment: Aceitei pois o código estava correto, e quando testei separadamente funcionou, mas  ao incrementar ao restante do código n funcionou mais

Comment: Então edite esta aqui com o código todo da sua e mais aquela, que fica mais fácil de ajudarmos.

Comment: reabra por favor, vendo que a resposta anterior n serve para esta pergunta n existe uma pergunta duplicada aqui

Comment: Você é que tem que fazer ela não ser duplicata. Da forma que está, o problema é o mesmo. Você pode [edit] a qualquer momento acrescentando o que tentou fazer, aí fica mais fácil de acharmos o erro. Ponha o código já com a parte que dá problema e o que usou da outra e não deu certo. Aí provavelmente vamos achar o erro com mais facilidade.

Comment: Já melhorou um bocado, mas faltou você usar a parte da outra resposta, não?

Comment: Olha, eu votei pra reabrir pra nao ficar causando mais tumulto, mas tente entender o que eu disse, que fica mais fácil pra você e pra gente. Da forma como está, eu ainda acho que não dá pra resolver, então veja o que você consegue fazer pra ficar mais fácil pra quem tá ajudando a entender o problema real. Veja isso como uma forma de você ajudar a quem ajudar você com respostas.

Comment: arrumei o código se tiver como achar o problema agora agradeceria

Answer (score 1):

## Teria algum 'comando' ou alguma coisa que possa usar para retornar apenas "exemplo" sem repetir a palavra?

A resposta para **está** pergunta é sim, mas para a pergunta em geral não há como respoder pois essa pergunta não foi muito bem 'arquitetada'.

```
implode(' ',array_unique(explode(' ', 'exemplo exemplo')));
```